# tasks distribution among nodes

Tags: node.js, hadoop, task, cloudera-manager

1. how map tasks are distributed among nodes.
2. Can i set nodes to run in parallel. 
   for example if datanodes are 2, and map tasks are 4 which of them take the task? i see from the manager sometimes datanode takes the task and sometimes the other datanode works. The job is given to both nodes and when any of them is assigned a task it runs one at a time.
   on what basis do the namenode assign tasks.
3. Is it done manually in the code or done auto. 
   If there is a link to a tutorial on how tasks run on nodes it will be great if you provided it.